# How do I get the Type of a generic parameter for a given method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, win-universal-app

Ok, here's the problem. I have a problem when comparing the return type of two different methods.

The first method is hard coded to a specific generic type, so when you get information on the method return type, it includes the type. Here's what I mean.

```
public Task<Message> GetMessage(long id)
{
    ...
    return await getEntityFromDbById<Message>(id); //generic type is hard coded to type Message
}
```

If you get the method info `this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetMessage").ReturnType.ToString()`, and look at it's return type, this is what you get

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Core.Models.Message]
```

Now, my second method is generic and looks like this.

```
public Task<T> GetEntityById<T>(long id) where T : class, IEntity
{
    ...
    return await getEntityFromDbById<T>(id); // generic type is passed in
}
```

Now if you get the ReturnType information for this method you get

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[T]
```

What I'm trying to do at runtime, is **get the type information of `T` and compare it to the other method using only MethodInfo types.** How can this be done?

```
public bool compareMethods(MethodInfo method1, MethodInfo method2)
{
    ...
    //Won't work because one method has a generic return type. 
    //How do you detect and compare?    
    return method1.ReturnType == method2.ReturnType; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a type reference, you can access the type of information of the references generic type parameters by using the method `GetGenericArguments()` which will return an array of type references for the generic parameters.

The same method is defined on `MethodInfo`.  Since you only have a single generic parameter in your declaration, you can actually just write:

```
public bool compareMethods(MethodInfo method1, MethodInfo method2)
{
    return method1.GetGenericArguments()[0] == method2.GetGenericArguments()[0]; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this out, but I get a `{Name = "T" FullName = null}` for one method, and `{Name = "Messsage" FullName = "Core.Models.Message"}` for the other.

Comment: @Matt - [1] Are you calling `GetGenericArguments()` on the method or the return type?  It looks like you're calling it on the return type which is a `Task<T>` in one case and a `Task<Message>` in the other?  [2] These two methods may not be comparable in the way you are thinking about them.  `GetEntityById<T> : long -> Task<T>` is an "open" generic method definition with an open generic return type whereas `GetMessage: long -> Task<Message>` is a non-generic method with a closed generic return type.  You'd need to have a closed call to `GetEntityById`  for their return types to be equal.

Comment: @smartcavman - I was afraid that this was the case. I'm going to have fun sorting this out, because what I want to do isn't possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Matt - you can push generics pretty far.  I honestly doubt that what you're trying to do "impossible" (unless there's a flaw in the logic of how you were thinking about it), but it might not be worth it to implement depending on your purpose.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @smartcavman - In a nut shell, I've modified the Moq test framework to work in a UWP app. Not everything is supported (which is ok), but one scenario I'm trying to get to work is with generics. In Moq, I can setup a generic method call like so `repo.Setup(p => p.GetEntityById<Message>(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(returnMessage).Verifiable()`. The problem is this expression is hard-coded to a `Message` entity, so the `method.ReturnType` is of type `Message`, but, since the method is generic, when I call it from my class `repo.GetEntityById<T>(id)`, the type is `T`

Comment: @Matt - Since you actually have a reference to the expression tree with the `MethodCallExpression` (and not just the `MethodInfo`) you should be able to write a visitor that will give you what you need.  It may not be as simple as comparing equality of the methods, but you haven't said anything to indicate it can't be done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm 100% ignorant of Expressions, but I recall seeing them used throughout the codebase. I'll look into it.